# How can I pass values from a view to a controller without using a form field?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a view that is a page for uploading files. This view calls a controller that needs a name passed into it as well as a list of the file names. I am able to pass in the list of file names just fine but I dont know how I can pass the customer name from my view back to my controller. I dont want to have a random textbox since I want to use the specific value already in Model.customerName.

Controller

```
public ActionResult UploadFiles(Customer customer)
{
     FileModel fileModel = new FileModel();
     fileModel.customerName = customer.Name;

     return View(fileModel);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UploadFiles(HttpPostedFileBase[] files)
{
      foreach (HttpPostedFileBase file in files)
      {
          if (file != null)
          {
              var ServerSavePath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Files/") + file.FileName);
              file.SaveAs(ServerSavePath);

              //upload to sharepoint
              UploadFileToSharePoint(ServerSavePath);

              ViewBag.UploadStatus = files.Length.ToString() + " files uploaded successfully.";
          }
      }

    return View();
}
```

View

```
@model Models.FileModel

@if (Model.customerName != null)
{
    <h2>@Model.customerName</h2>
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("UploadFiles", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{ 
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.files, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.files, "", new { @type = "file", @multiple = "multiple" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.files, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit"  value="Upload" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10 text-success">
                @ViewBag.UploadStatus
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
}
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

I tried passing it in after the enctype = "multipart/form-data", but it appeared as null in my controller.

**UPDATE:**
I ended up using a hidden field in my view.

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.customerName, new {Value = Model.customerName})
```

And in my controller I had to grab the FormCollection

```
public ActionResult UploadFiles(System.Web.Mvc.FormCollection fc, 
HttpPostedFileBase[] files)
{
      string customerName = fc["customerName"];
      ...
}
```

Comment: Bind the Name to a HiddenField?

Comment: ok I will try it out.

Comment: `@using (Html.BeginForm("UploadFiles", "Home", new { name = Model.Name }, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))` and add an additional parameter `string name` to your POST method

Comment: my parameter in my post method is null when I try this

Comment: please note that hidden fields are hidden from rendering only, they will still be visible in the source, so scraping tools can find them. you may use `session` objects as well if you need more security.

Comment: ok thanks for the heads up

Comment: The parameter will NOT be `null`!

Comment: I guess something else was causing it to be null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass model data through a view by using hidden fields.

You can use [`Html.HiddenFor()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.inputextensions.hiddenfor(v=vs.118).aspx) or simply `<div hidden>`

Comment: The question states _without using a form field_

Comment: I think this helped. I had to get the FormCollection from my controller method and it finally passed the value

Answer (score 1):

Everything you did was correct , except  the correct overload that is  you have to use, this overload of beginform()

```
public static MvcForm BeginForm(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string actionName,
    string controllerName,
    object routeValues,
    FormMethod method,
    object htmlAttributes
)
```

Here you have to pass the route values before the form method like the below example

Your Example:

**View code:**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("UploadFiles", "Home",new{cusname = Model.customerName }, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{ 
       //any logic
}
```

Controller Code:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UploadFiles(HttpPostedFileBase[] files,string cusname) 
{
     //any logic
}
```

Hope the above code was helpful

Thanks

Karthik

Comment: When I try this my cusname parameter in my controller is null